# Dockerfile and Docker run -w / workdir

Tags: docker

Let's take the sample python dockerfile as an example.

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /project
COPY . /project
```

and then the run command to run the tests with in that container:

`docker run --rm -v$(CWD):/project -w/project mydocker:1.0 pytest tests/`

We are declaring the WORKDIR in the dockerfile and the run.

Am I right in saying

The `WORKDIR` in the dockerfile is the directory which the subsequent commands in the Dockerfile are run? But this will have no impact on when we run the `docker run` command?

Instead we need to pas in the `-w/project` to have pytests run in the /projects directory, well for pytest to look for the rests directory in /projects.

My setup.cfg

```
[tool:pytest]
addopts =
    --junitxml=results/unit-tests.xml
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. When you're already specifying `WORKDIR` in your Dockerfile, why the need to specify it in the `docker run` command? If you're using `-w some-other-dir` during `docker run`, it will have effect because you're using `CMD` instruction in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Sorry, there is no CMD in the dockerfile. My question is if I don't specify WORKDIR in the `docker run` which directory does pytest get run in?

Comment: Even if the `CMD` is not there, you're still specifying the working dir both in the Dockerfile and command line. If all you need to do is `COPY` some stuff in your image to `/project` dir, you can do it without using `WORKDIR` instruction also.

Comment: This is my question. What is the difference. Because if I remove it from the `docker run` it does not work and the pytest output is not put in the /project directory.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you give, you shouldn't need either the `-v` or `-w` option.

Various options in the Dockerfile give defaults that can be overridden at `docker run` time.  `CMD` in the Dockerfile, for example, will be overridden by anything in a `docker run` command after the image name.  (...and it's better to specify it in the Dockerfile than to have to manually specify it on every `docker run` invocation.)

Specifically to your question, `WORKDIR` affects the current directory for subsequent `RUN` and `COPY` commands, but it also specifies the default directory when the container runs; if you don't have a `docker run -w` option it will use that `WORKDIR`.  Specifying `-w` to the same directory as the final image `WORKDIR` won't have an effect.

You also `COPY` the code into your image in the Dockerfile (which is good).  You don't need a `docker run -v` option to overwrite that code at run time.

More specifically looking at pytest, it won't usually write things out to the filesystem.  If you are using functionality like JUnit XML or code coverage reports, you can set it to write those out somewhere other than your application directory:

```
docker run --rm \
  -v $PWD/reports:/reports \
  mydocker:1.0 \
  pytest --cov=myapp --cov-report=html:/reports/coverage.html tests
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's very helpful. I have updated the question with the setup.cfg which states the output for the tests. 

What is interesting is if I remove the `-w/project` from the `docker run` command the output file does not exist in the host. However, with the `-w/project` in the run it does appear there. I am trying to work out why.

Comment: If you're trying to run unit tests, and the end goal is to get a report file on the host, you don't need Docker at all.  Create a Python virtual environment if you haven't already and run `pytest` directly on the host.

Comment: It needs to be in docker for various reasons. Regardless, I'm trying to learn more about Docker so this is useful to troubleshoot regardless.